# How do I use superpixel function in opencv-android

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, android

I went through the documentation of the OpenCV superpixel function in Python/c++, but I can't find any for android/java. I can't find any superpixel function in OpenCV Android, although I'm able to find other OpenCV functions.

Is there a specific way to load the superpixel function in OpenCV?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of opencv are you using? Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020247/superpixelslic-image-grainy)

Comment: I'm having trouble including the opencv_contrib modules..

Answer (score -1):

you can use SLIC SuperPixel function with opencv_contrib for android